# Two touching circles, common tangent, proof

Tags: analytic-geometry

Two circles A and B are touching and have a common tangent which meets A at M and B at N. Let MP be a diameter of A and let the tangent from P to B touch it at Q Show that MP=PQ

I've drawn it out and a few different lines through the shape to try to get a new perspective, labelled all the angles and sides but didn't get anywhere... would really appreciate the help, I've been trying a few hours now[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/567tJ.jpg)

Comment: There are *two* tangents from $P$ to $B$.

Comment: In geometry you better add a diagram...in particular when the explanations aren't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Proof sketch with inversion**: Invert through $P$ with radius $PM$, and denote the inversions with $'$. Clearly $P=P'$ and $M=M'$, and write the common tangent as $l$. Now, $l' = A$ (and $A'=l$), so consider $B'$. In particular, $B'$ must lie tangent to $A'=l$ and $l'=A$, and to $PQ'$. We don't yet know where $Q'$ lies, but it is certainly on the line $PQ$, so $B'$ is tangent to $l$, $A$ and $PQ$. But $B$ is tangent to these, and it is not hard to see now that $B=B'$. Furthermore, $Q=Q'$, so $PM = PQ$, as required.

The important idea here is that the *whole diagram* is invariant under this particular inversion.

Comment: Thank you! Figured it out now. Took me a while to research circle inversion. Do you have any recommendations for books or websites on it? @mehta

Comment: Perhaps this isn't the best proof if you don't already know inversion, but it's surprisingly clean if you do. I recall using [IMOmath](http://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=323) and [this paper](http://www.geometer.org/mathcircles/inversion.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! These are surprisingly fun... Found some more practice questions online too